# i have to click twice, why? (JavaScript onclick event handler)

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am new to JavaScript and web development and it is the first time i see this kind of bugs. it is a very basic example, i have two divs- left and right- the left one has five images and the right one is empty , i have also two buttons copy and delete, each has an onclick event handler. the Copy button copies the entire left node (div) and appends it to the right div , the delete button should delete the last image in the right div and it does, the thing is i have to click twice on Delete button to delete one image so i have to click 10 times to delete the entire set. why this happens? what should i do to make the Delete button deletes an image by just clicking once ?

this is my entire code , tested on Microsoft Edge and Google chrome and i got the same result.

```js
var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");
var theRightSide = document.getElementById("rightSide");


function Copy() {
  copy = theLeftSide.cloneNode(true);
  theRightSide.appendChild(copy);
}

function Delete() {
  copy.removeChild(copy.lastChild);
}
```

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 670px;
  height: 520px;
  background: red
}
#rightSide {
  position: absolute;
  left: 670px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  background: black
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Copy" onclick="Copy()">
<input type="button" value="delete" id="btn" onclick="Delete()">

<div id="leftSide" style="width:400px">
  <img src="smile.png" />
  <img src="smile.png" />
  <img src="smile.png" />
  <img src="smile.png" />
  <img src="smile.png" />
</div>

<div id="rightSide">

</div>
```

Comment: IDs must be unique, and when you clone the div you duplicate IDs. Also, the white space between your images counts as a child.

Comment: Few advices - declare copy variable first, otherwise 'use-strict' will throw error, and its a bad practice. Follow the comment by j08691. So do not just make clones, rather copy images one by one or encapsulate it inside another div with no id. Answer by L. Catallo is also somewhat true, select child nodes and then delete it. Also please tell us after loading the page, if this 'twice click' problem is happening only for first time or everytime?

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers instert by default an empty text node between each element of your page, your code is deleting one empty node for every img, that's why it seems to work half of the times.

Try this:

```
function Delete(){
  var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('.rightSide img');
  copy.removeChild(imgs[imgs.length-1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're removing text nodes as well as elements. What you really want is `copy.removeChild(copy.lastElementChild);`

Comment: I would also recommend placing `var copy` at the top of that script. `copy` is an actual function in Chrome.